# Backup a File or Folder when dropping it on the same bat

Tags: batch-file, backup, file-copying

So I've managed to cobble together a script witch works as intended for files when using "copy". It creates a backup folder "_OLD" and makes an iterated (file001, file002, etc) copy of the file I dropped on my bat by checking for the highest version in the backup folder. How ever I would like to have only one bat that would work the same way for both a file or folder. By substituting "copy" with "xcopy" I managed to copy the folder but now the file wont be copied at all. I know a little bit of programing but I'm not very experienced with bat scripts. Is there an easy fix to make it work the same on both a file and folder?

```
@echo off
rem set this to whatever you like
set "BackupFolderName=_OLD"

rem splits filename into name and extension etc for processing
set "OutputFolder=%CD%\%BackupFolderName%"
set "FullPath=%~1"
set "Filename=%~n1"
set "Ext=%~x1"

rem creates an output folder if none exist
if not exist "%OutputFolder%" mkdir "%OutputFolder%"

rem find the highest version of the file
set a=1
set pad=00000

:loop
rem leading zeroes
SET b=%pad%%a%
rem %var:~10% gets the sub-string from index 10 to the end of %var%
SET b=%b:~-3%
if exist "%OutputFolder%\%Filename%%b%%Ext%" set /a a+=1 && goto :loop

echo "Backed up %FilenameExt% as %Filename%%b%%Ext% in %BackupFolderName%"
xcopy /s/y "%FullPath%" "%OutputFolder%\%Filename%%b%%Ext%"


rem pause
timeout 1 >nul
exit
```

Here is my final code that takes multiple files or folders and does a backup of them:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem set this output folder name to whatever you like eg _OLD
set "BackupFolderName=_OLD"
rem creates an output folder, if none exist
set "OutputFolder=%CD%\%BackupFolderName%"
if not exist "%OutputFolder%" mkdir "%OutputFolder%"

rem loops through all the files dropped on bat
FOR %%G IN (%*) DO (call :sub %%G)
goto :end

:sub
rem splits filename into name and extension etc for processing
set "FullPath=%~1"
set "Filename=%~n1"
set "Ext=%~x1"


rem rem find the highest version of the file
set a=1
set pad=00000

:loop
rem leading zeroes
SET b=%pad%%a%
rem %var:~10% gets the sub-string from index 10 to the end of %var%
SET b=%b:~-3%
if exist "%OutputFolder%\%Filename%%b%%Ext%" set /a a+=1 && goto :loop


rem rem checks if dropped item is file or folder
set type=invalid
for %%F in ("%~1") do (echo/%%~aF|findstr /bc:"d" >nul && set type=folder)
for %%F in ("%~1") do (echo/%%~aF|findstr /bc:"-" >nul && set type=file)

rem copies file or folder to destination
if %type%==file (copy "%FullPath%" "%OutputFolder%\%Filename%%b%%Ext%" >nul)
if %type%==folder (xcopy /s/y/q "%FullPath%" "%OutputFolder%\%Filename%%b%%Ext%\" >nul)

echo "Backed up %Filename% as %Filename%%b%%Ext% in %BackupFolderName%"
goto :eof

:end
pause
rem timeout 1 >nul
rem exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the file attributes (see `for /?`)

```
@echo off
setlocal

set type=invalid
for %%F in ("%~1") do (echo/%%~aF|findstr /bc:"d" >nul && set type=folder)
for %%F in ("%~1") do (echo/%%~aF|findstr /bc:"-" >nul && set type=file)
echo %type%
```